# Jsf control that format text with html tags

Tags: jsf

Good morning all.

Is there any jsf control that escapes the html tags?

Imagine that i have the following string in resources:

```
text.String=lalala<br/>lelele
```

and i want to print it on Xhtml file with a simple control like:

```
<h:outputText value="#{messages['text.String']}" />
```

how do i get the result formatted with the html `<br/>` tag?
Result should be:

```
lalala
lelele
```

instead of: 
`lalala<br/>lelele`

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the outputText control has an 'escape' property which controls that behaviour.
See [here (outputText reference).](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_outputText.html)

So basically:

```
<h:outputText escape="false" value="#{messages['text.String']}" />
```

should do the job.

Comment: Anybody knows how to do it with a h:message tag? There is no escape property on h:message.